# Do helium and neon form "stable" chemical compounds?

Tags: noble-gases, chemical-potential

Helium and neon are the two most unreactive elements in the Periodic Table, but could they form  compounds with an element such as fluorine that won't spontaneously explode and decompose outside of the lab? Radon, xenon, krypton, and even argon already do form fluorides(well argon forms argon fluorohydride). It said in my Wikipedia source that helium supposedly made a compound with fluorine,but I'm confused with that. Is there any known evidence that this is true?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas_compound

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_compounds

Comment: Yes, sure helium and neon are the most unreactive elements but it doesn't mean it can't form compounds. Given the condition, they are known to make clathrates, fullerenes etc. Have a good read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_compounds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_compounds

Comment: I think the OP might be looking for the mechanism behind this reaction. Maybe he should include in the title